# How to find lowest value at the time (lap records) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with laptimes. I'm looking for a way to find the lowest laptime at the time (ie a lap record), compared to earlier entries. I'm just learning MySQL for fun, and I am still a beginnner.
(I will use this to create a graph for the lap record over time.)

I have a table like this:

```
create table temp_laptimes(
lap_id INT NOT NULL,
driver VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
laptime FLOAT(5,1) NOT NULL,
lap_date DATE,
PRIMARY KEY ( lap_id )
);

INSERT INTO `temp_laptimes` (`lap_id`, `driver`, `laptime`, `lap_date`) 
VALUES 
('1', 'Dean', '56.8', '2019-01-01'),
('22', 'Zach', '59.7', '2019-02-01'),
('33', 'Carl', '56.1', '2019-03-01'),
('42', 'Zoe', '56.3', '2019-04-01'),
('50', 'Zach', '56.4', '2019-05-01'),
('61', 'Bob', '55.9', '2019-06-01'),
('73', 'Zeb', '56.2', '2019-07-01'),
('84', 'Anne', '55.7', '2019-08-01'),
('95', 'Dean', '55.9', '2019-09-01');
```

I want to find the lap records over time, ie a result like this:

```
1  Dean  56.8  2019-01-01
33 Carl  56.1  2019-03-01
61 Bob   55.9  2019-06-01
84 Anne  55.7  2019-08-01
```

Dean set the first laptime, so that's the first lap record. Then Carl beat that, then Bob beat that, and finally Anne beat that, holding the current record.

MySQL running on a shared host. As you see, lap_id is not continous.

I have tried things like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `temp_laptimes` t1
JOIN (
SELECT lap_id, driver, laptime, lap_date
FROM temp_laptimes
GROUP BY laptime
)
AS t2 ON  t1.laptime < t2.laptime AND t1.lap_date > t2.lap_date
ORDER BY t1.laptime ASC
```

which apparently seems to find all occurences where a later laptime is lower than a previous laptime. For instance, Anne appears 7 times in the result, because she beat 7 different laptimes with her laptime. Bob appears 5 times. Zoe appears 1 time, cause she beat Zachs previous time.

But I don't know how to sort out just the lap records.

As I said, I'm a novice, and thankful for any help and pointers in the right direction. This is just a hobby project I'm doing for fun. Also, English is not my first language, so apologies if I'm unclear in my explanation. Thanks.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: MySQL 5.6 as far as I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NOT EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery would do the trick, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM temp_laptimes t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM temp_laptimes t1
    WHERE t1.lap_date < t.lap_date AND t1.laptime < t.laptime
)
```

The `NOT EXISTS` condition ensures that there is no previous record that has a smaller lap time.

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w351Mwog989eBKKtdNCEQc/0)**:

```
| lap_id | driver | laptime | lap_date   |
| ------ | ------ | ------- | ---------- |
| 1      | Dean   | 56.8    | 2019-01-01 |
| 33     | Carl   | 56.1    | 2019-03-01 |
| 61     | Bob    | 55.9    | 2019-06-01 |
| 84     | Anne   | 55.7    | 2019-08-01 |
```

---

If you are using MySQL 8.0, another, potentially more efficient method, is to use a window function in a subquery to compute the minimum lap time across the current and preceding record. Then, the outer query filters out on records where the minimum is equal to the current lap time:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
      t.*, 
      MIN(laptime) OVER(ORDER BY lap_date) min_lap_time
  FROM temp_laptimes t
) x WHERE laptime = min_lap_time;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w351Mwog989eBKKtdNCEQc/1)** (same results).

Comment: Thank you! This works beautifully! Apparently I'm on MySQL 5.6, so I'll stick with the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a correlated subquery for this:

```
select lt.*
from temp_laptimes lt
where lt.laptime = (select min(lt2.laptime)
                    from temp_laptimes lt2
                    where lt2.lapdate <= lt.lapdate
                   );
```

However, the cumulative window function suggested by gmb is better in MySQL 8+.